# How to update multiple row session in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want after clicking the "Submit" button, all the lines of the form are updated. After I change the quantity ordered, then all will be saved in the session cart. I want to handle by hand so I did not use any gem.

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag do %>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product name</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>SubPrice</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <br>

            <% @cart.each do |id, quantity| %>
            <tr>
                <% product = Product.find_by_id(id) %>
                <td><%= link_to product.name, product %></td>
                <td><%= image_tag(product.image.thumb('45x45#').url, class: "SlideItMoo_element") if product.image_stored? %></td>
                <td><%= product.description.html_safe %></td>
                <td><%= product.price * quantity %></td>
                <td><%= number_field_tag :quantity, quantity %></td>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :id, value: id %>
                <td><%= link_to 'remove', cart_remove_product_path(id) %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

cart_controller.rb

```
class CartController < ApplicationController
    def addCart
        id = params[:id]
        if session[:cart] then
            cart = session[:cart]
        else
            session[:cart] ={}
            cart = session[:cart]
        end
        if cart[id] then
            cart[id] = cart[id] + 1
        else
            cart[id] = 1
        end
        redirect_to :action => :index
    end

    def clearCart
        session[:cart] = nil
        redirect_to :action => :index
    end

    def index
        if session[:cart] then
            @cart = session[:cart]
        else
            @cart = {}
        end
    end

    def cartRemoveProduct
        id = params[:id]
        session[:cart].delete(id)
        redirect_to :action => :index
    end

    def cartChangeProductQuantity
        @idProduct  = eval(quan[:id])[:value].to_i
        cart = session[:cart]
        cart.each do |id, quantity|
            @ide = id
            if id.to_i == @idProduct then
                cart[id] = quan[:quantity].to_i
            end
        end
        redirect_to :action => :index
    end

    private
    def quan
      params.permit(:quantity, :id)
    end

end
```

I was able to update the final products of the line. Thanks

Comment: i don't actually understand your question can you elaborate.... this

Comment: @TanmayAgrawal I mean, I want to update the quantity of products ordered in sesion cart[id] when users change the quantity and click submit button. As the code above, I can only update the last line after the user changes the quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add array to storage all quantity in form.

```
def cartChangeProductQuantity
        cart = session[:cart]
        @quanid = quan[:ids]
        @h = cartGetIdQuan(@quanid)
        @m = quan[:quantitys]
        i = 0
        j = 0
        while i < @h.size
            cart.each do |id, quantity|
                if @h[i] == id.to_i then
                    cart[id] = @m[i].to_i
                end
            end
            i+=1
        end
    end

    private
    def quan
      params.permit(:quantitys => [], :ids => [])
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to work with remote.

```
form_tag @ressource, :remote => true
```

Your form should be `_form.html.erb`
inside your view `render "form"`

then in your controller

```
def action_form
  ....
  respond_to |format| do
   format.js
  end
end
```

and you've a file which display your form with updated information

`action_form.js.erb`

`$('#content').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("form")) %>')`

`#content` refer to the div which contain the form

inside action_form.js you can add more jquery if you want it to trigger more action

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how I can get all of the products id in the session cart to update quantity?

Comment: I think that the best way is to add a remote link like '-' and '+' which is doing the action in remote for the database storage and respond in the jquery with the change of display

Comment: or add a remote form with an integer field but imo, it's not worth for the UX

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try to do the way you have said.